# Can't close a MongoDB connection with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It seems that I can't close a MongoDB connection with Node.js native driver. When I run `node replica.js` the script never ends, hence the connection can't be closed for some reason.

Here is the code. It's a replica set but I don't think that it's a problem:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb')
  , Db      = mongodb.Db
  , Server  = mongodb.Server
  , ReplSet = mongodb.ReplSet;

// Replica set
var replSet = new ReplSet( [
    new Server('localhost', 27017), // Primary
    new Server('localhost', 27018), // Secondary
    new Server('localhost', 27016), // Secondary
  ],
  { rs_name: 'replica', read_secondary: true }
);

var db = new Db('test', replSet, { native_parser: true, w: 1 });

// Opening
db.open(function (err, db) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    db.close();
});
```

Connecting to a single mongod instance works just fine, connection get closed and the script ends, without the need (suggested by robertklep) of `process.exit()` call:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb')
  , Db      = mongodb.Db
  , Server  = mongodb.Server;

// Single instance
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017):
var db = new Db('test', server, { native_parser: true, w: 1 });

// Opening
db.open(function (err, db) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that it was a bug, now fixed in 1.3.6. Look at [this issue I opened](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/976) few days ago. The funny thing is that it's my first time with MongoDB...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to force the pool of connections to close in this case by passing `true` as the first parameter to [`close`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#close).  You should also provide a callback so that you can be alerted to any problems when trying to close:

```
db.open(function (err, db) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    db.close(true, function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        else console.log("close complete");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why my second example works without forcing, but I need to force close the connection with replica set?

Comment: @Gremo You shouldn't need to, but something unexpected is going on.  Does the callback get called without an error?

Comment: No errors at all. Even using `close(true)` doesn't help. Your code prints "close complete" and it never exit the script. I need to force close with `CTRL + C`.